# How to iterate all row and column in the objectresult

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities

Is there a way to iterate the objectResult? 
I.e. Just like iterate all column and row for datatable without specify the column name.

I like to create a generic function which will display all column of the object result. So is that possible to achieve this?

```
Dim queryResults As Data.Objects.ObjectResult = CType(obj, Data.Objects.ObjectResult)

    If Not (queryResults Is Nothing) Then

        ' Create the representation. 
        Dim result As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        Dim enumerator As System.Collections.IEnumerator = Nothing
        enumerator = DirectCast(queryResults, System.Collections.IEnumerable).GetEnumerator()

        ' Iterate through the query results.  
        While enumerator.MoveNext() 
         ''How to get all columns ???
        End While
        ' Dispose the enumerator  
        DirectCast(enumerator, IDisposable).Dispose()





        Return result
    End If
    Return New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
```

Comment: can you update question with code which you tried so far

Comment: there is nothing more than what you show me,             Dim enumerator As System.Collections.IEnumerator = Nothing
            enumerator = DirectCast(queryResults, System.Collections.IEnumerable).GetEnumerator()

            ' Iterate through the query results.  
            While enumerator.MoveNext() 

            End While

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way :

```
DataTable table = GetTable(); // Your Query to Get the data table.
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
{

    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray) // Loop over the items.
    {
       Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```